# JAX-RS - optional request body

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs, option-type

I have a REST endpoint that accepts JSON in the request body. The JSON is automatically unmarshalled to a POJO using the provider `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider`. I would like to make the request body optional, but currently if I don't supply at least an empty JSON object, I get an internal server error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;
```

Is it possible to make it optional?

Comment: Did you ever hear back on this?  I've got a method that needs to optionally accept an InputStream for an image.  Sometimes I may get the image, other times I will not.

Comment: @bmauter No I didn't but I would investigate whether using the `com.fasterxml` version for the provider has the same issues.

Comment: Which JavaEE spec version do you use? JBoss 6 supports JavaEE 6 which contains JAX-RS 1.1 spec verson only. I strongly assume you try to use JAX-RS 2.x features which is not supported in JBoss 6.  If it's possible upgrade container version.

Answer (score -1):

Writing here as i'd the same issue.

Overloading the `@POST` annotated method with no body helped me. I'm using a JBoss 6 with RestEASY

Comment: Sorry, but it's not an answer.

Comment: I was work but intermittent.